# What is easiest way to merge two or more pdf files in Delphi?

Tags: delphi

I'd like to be able to merge multiple pdfs into one file using Delphi 2009.  I'd be willing to look at third party components for this.

Please do not suggest Gnostice's products - I have tried to use them for this and have been disappointed so far.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way that I have found was to use a free command-line program, pdftk

http://www.pdftk.com/

Merge Two or More PDFs into a New Document:

`pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf 3.pdf cat output 123.pdf`

Comment: That is a cool idea; thanks for the tip: I'm a command-line addict (even have a nipple mouse in my keyboard, as external mice give me RSI).

Answer (score 0):

If you have Adobe writer / creator could you automate it? I believe there is an SDK...

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [Amyuni PDF Creator ActiveX](http://www.amyuni.com/en/developer/pdfcreatoractivex) for this task. There is a C# example in [a SO answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6394834/stamp-a-pdf-with-another-pdf-alternative-to-aspose-pdf-kits-pdffilestamp-class/6413367#6413367), the Delphi equivalent would be very similar.
*Disclaimer: I am part of the development team of this product.*

Answer (score 0):

Use Debenu.Quick.PDF.Library there are Methods for merging.